# Copying a git-svn repo from Linux(wsl) to Windows

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Currently, I want to import an svn repo onto my local disk. This takes a day and a half on WSL using the standard git-svn command.

However, when I try and copy this to windows (/mnt/c), it copies it, but fails for three files with: can't copy file, file already exists. This I believe is probably due to the case-insensitive nature of windows.

I have tried several times to use git-svn on windows unsuccessfully. It takes much longer and always crashes in strange way, such that re-running git svn fetch no longer works (often complaining about .lock files existing, which sometimes can be fixed by deleting them) or memory leaking.

Is there a way to make git-svn fetch a case-insensitive repo in WSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVN repo contains files that differ only in case. Therefore, when Git checks out those files on a case-sensitive file system, it has two files with different contents. When you copy that to an NTFS drive, you can't represent both of those files.

You can try copying the repository with `cp -fR` in an attempt to overwrite the files that already exist, but your Git repository will always show some files as modified.

You can also try [setting your destination directory as case-sensitive](https://www.howtogeek.com/354220/how-to-enable-case-sensitive-folders-on-windows-10/) on NTFS, which will allow your copy to work as expected.

Comment: Are you sure? When I  checkout my SVN repo in windows (using just subversion), it seems to work. Doesn't that imply there can't be any files differing only in case? I will try that case sensitive trick when I re-download the repository!

Comment: It's possible that instead you have multiple branches that differ only in case. There's clearly something that's triggering a case issue. You haven't said what the files are, so we can only guess.

Comment: setting my directory as case sensitive worked (although it tends to make some programs behave strangely if you have files differing only in case). The problem with the changed files seems to be a newline problem, which i think the linux shell automatically blats? Only these files seem to have the problem though. Anyway, everything seems to be working!